# how to optimise image links in magento

Tags: image, product-images, optimization

i am using magento and trying to speed up my site.

one of the obviouse error gt matrix and google tool is giving to optmise my images.

i am bit confuse here as my site only host few banners etc, rest of all images (product images) are hosted on a third party website, and my site just receive a link for image and then show that image on front end.

just for your record i use stock in the channel and there plugin.

i do not have any controll on those images. so how can i optimize them?

i have been looking for a decent (free) plugin which can help me but couldnt find any.

your help in this matter will be apreciated.

note: i already have installed fooman speedster to combine my css and javascript but i dont think it optimise site images or image links.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a reverse proxy like CloudFlare between the third party website (if it supports images being accessed from a different domain) that hosts your images if those images aren't compressed enough. Or you can create your own script that does `file_get_contents` and compresses the image.